# Why do some GPS modules in smartphones have two or more antennas?

Tags: antenna, gps, gnss

Some GPS modules have only one antenna, but some of them have two and more. For what? Are they made for different frequencies and ranges?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which one ?  Galaxy S has 6 antenna but only 1 for GPS.  https://medium.com/@importanttech/we-tested-mobile-gps-gnss-accuracy-and-found-some-surprising-results-b9ec35873e2e